# Can Xamarin iOS run iPhone simulator from Win7/Parallels/VS2013 on MacBook Pro

Tags: iphone, xcode, visual-studio-2013, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I have a MacBook Pro w/ XCode and am running a Parallels win7 VM w/ VS2013 and Xamarin iOS installed. I do not have a separate Mac server, i.e., this is all on one physical computer.

Can I run/test my iPhone app the iPhone simulator? If so, references to documentation, samples, etc would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use your MBP as a build host while using VS2013 inside of a VM.

The [Xamarin Docs](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/introduction_to_xamarin_ios_for_visual_studio/) cover how to set this up.